# Silverlight : Custom template for a hierarchy treeview

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, controls

I am using silverlight and want to dynamically generate a hierararchy tree in the following format :

[Hierararchy tree view http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/4889/treeview.jpg](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/4889/treeview.jpg)

Since Silverlight controls are lookless,how can I structure a template that ultimately look like the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this in WPF, but not Silverlight.  Don't have the code handy now, but two resources I used were:

- [Custom TreeView Layout in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomTreeViewLayout.aspx)
- [Turning a Treeview into an Org Chart (with Connectors!)](http://wpfblog.info/2008/05/26/turning-a-treeview-into-an-org-chart-with-connectors/)

The layout bit is not that hard.  Connectors are a bit more difficult, especially if things are moving around.

Comment: Thanks,they acheived the effect I needed